# Excel Web App dropdown control issues

Tags: excel-services, office-web-apps

Happy New Year everyone,

I am having some strange issues with our on-prem SharePoint 2013 environment. When a user opens an excel document in Excel Web App in IE, the dropdown controls (edit workbook, share, data) do not work properly (when you click them they do not respond).

I am able to replicate the issue on my laptop running IE11, and other users are reporting the same issue, though I am unsure which version of IE they are using (it is likely IE9 or below for compatibility with our Oracle system. The dropdowns work fine on my desktop, running IE9, as well as when I use Google Chrome on either device.

Could there be something wrong with our browser settings for IE that would cause this issue on some computers but not others?

Thanks for reading, hope you can help.
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a permissions issue regarding the custom permissions level that was created for this group. Once I enabled 'Use Client Integration Features' for that permission level everything began operating properly.